# Verifying sendKeys result in a Page Object file results in undefined error (Protractor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

So, I have a page object file that provides a number of methods for the elements on a page. The page is a login page with some text, a username and password input elements, and a login button. I've created a generic object called "InputLabel.js" which ties the label and input element together for testing purposes.

The problem I'm having is that after I clear the input, send the data, and then verify the data, I'm getting a `Failed: Cannot read property 'verifyValue' of undefined` error.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// InputLabel.js

function InputLabel(container) {
    this.Container = container;
}

InputLabel.prototype = {
    constructor: InputLabel,
    // ...
    /**
     * Return the element for the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     * 
     * @returns {ElementFinder}
     */
    getInput: function () {
        return this.Container.$('input');
    },
    /**
     * Return the text shown in the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     * 
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    getValue: function () {
        return this.getInput().getAttribute('value');
    },
    /**
     * Verify the text shown in the input of the input/label combination of elements.
     * 
     * @param expected The expected text in the input element.
     */
    verifyValue: function (expected) {
        console.log('Asserting input value [' + expected + ']');
        expect(this.getValue()).toEqual(expected);
    },
    // ...
    /**
     * Clears the input element then puts the text from data into the input element.
     * 
     * @param data The text to be entered into the input element.
     */
    sendKeys: function (data) {
        var el = this.getInput();
        el.clear().then(function () {
            el.sendKeys(data).then(function () {
                console.log("Verifying [" + data + "] was sent to the input.")
                this.verifyValue(data);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

After requiring the file, I can call any of these methods without issue except the sendKeys.  If I disabled the `this.verifyValue(data);` method, sendKeys works fine.

```
// LoginPage.js

var InputLabel = require('InputLabel.js');

function LoginPage() {
}

var username = new InputLabel($('#username'));
var password = new InputLabel($('#password'));

function.prototype = {
   // ...
   username: username,
   password: password,
   loginButton: {
      get: function() { return $('#Login'); },
      click: function() { return this.get().click(); }
   },
   // ...
   login: function(user, pw) {
      this.username.sendKeys(user);
      this.password.sendKeys(pw);
      this.loginButton.click()
   }
}
```

Am I losing something in scope?  Again, the error is that it fails because it cannot read property 'verifyValue' of undefined after sending the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scoping issue with "this" keyword on the line containing "this.verifyValue(data);". In this case "this" keyword doesn't refer to the InputLabel class. Also it is considered a good practice to keep page objects assertion-free. See http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html

Comment: When I took "this." off of it, I still get the same error. `Failed: verifyValue is not defined`.  I will, however, take a look at your link and learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: Once you get inside that first promise `el.clear()` you lose the scope for `this` as @finspin said. At the base level of your `sendKeys` function put `var self = this;` (which will keep you scoped to the InputLabel), and then use `self.verifyValue(data);`

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful. Since I've run into it again. (I'm still learning the javascript style.)